# Combining dictionary values in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dicts from a web log in python, say for example something like this:

```
log = [
    {'customer id': 'Tom',
    'activity': 'view cart',
    'time': '2014-07-29 12:15:45.113',
    'sesion_id': '86487asr341542343dwrasd4'},

    {'customer id': 'Jim',
    'activity': 'view cart',
    'time': '2014-07-29 12:15:48.113',
    'sesion_id': '86487asr341542343dlrasd4'},

    {'customer id': 'Tom',
    'activity': 'checkout',
    'time': '2014-07-29 12:17:48.113',
    'sesion_id': '86487asr341542343dwrasd4'},

    ....
]
```

My list is much larger, but this should convey what it might look like.

What I am trying to do is make a new list of dicts, where ALL of the activities for an individual user are captured under that user, maybe something like this:

```
user_activity = [
    {'customer': 'Tom', 'activities': [
        {'activity': 'view cart',
        'time': '2014-07-29 12:15:45.113'},
        {'activity': 'checkout',
        'time': '2014-07-29 12:17:48.113'}
        ]
    },
    {'customer': 'Jim', activities..............
    }
]
```

I dont want to capture every field from the first list (for example, i dont care about session id).

This is what I have so far, and it doesnt work. I am fairly certain its COMPLETELY off base, because I keep getting error messages like 'list has no attribute keys':

```
for activity in log:
    cust = activity['customer id']
    if cust not in user_activity.keys():
        user_activity.append({'customer': cust, 'activities': []})
    user_activity[cust]['activities'].append({'time': activity['time'],
                  'activity': activity['activity']})
```

I am sure there is an easier way to do this, maybe using list comprehension or something, but I am not seeing it.

Comment: make user_activity a dictionary and use the customer name as the key

Comment: @JoranBeasley: That's exactly what he's doing; look at the end. He just wants better code to convert what he has into that format.

Comment: Just a suggestion: based on the data you keep, your desired output might be less than ideal (and probably making your task more difficult).  I'm not sure what you plan to do with it so this may not be applicable, but I would suggest something like this: ```user_activity = {"Tom":[("view cart", "2014-07-29"), ("checkout", "2014-07-29")], "Jim": [...]}```

Comment: As a side note, instead of checking `it foo not in foodict:` and adding an empty value, use the `setdefault` method, or a `collections.defaultdict`. For example: `user_activity.setdefault(cust, []).append(whatever)` will append `whatever` to the list if one already exists, or create an empty list and append `whatever` to that if not.

Comment: Also, you don't need `foo in foodict.keys()`; a dictionary is already a container of its keys, so `foo in foodict` does the same thing. (And, in Python 2.x, it does it much more efficiently, too; in 3.x, there's not much difference.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to `append` to `user_activity`, which is a dictionary (judging by your use of `.keys`) and doesn't have any such method. Replace the `append` call as follows:

```
for activity in log:
cust = activity['customer id']
if cust not in user_activity.keys():
    user_activity[cust] = {'activities': []}
user_activity[cust]['activities'].append({'time': activity['time'],
              'activity': activity['activity']})
```

And it will work.

Comment: Or, alternatively, if `user_activity` is a `list` and therefore doesn't have `.keys`… change it to a `dict` and then follow this answer.

Comment: This does exactly what I need it to, although not exactly the way I was trying to do it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this in one big expression, you can. I'm not sure you *should*, but since you asked for it, and since there are other cases where this is useful…

If you can group together all the activities for each customer, you can then transform each group into a list.

`itertools.groupby` can do the grouping, but only if you first sort the values by customer.

So:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> sortedlog = sorted(log, key=itemgetter('customer id'))
>>> groups = groupby(sortedlog, key=itemgetter('customer id'))
```

Since `groupby` gives you an iterator full of iterators, it can be a bit hard to see what it's doing, so for the sake of demonstration, let's turn it into a bunch of lists. (You do not need—or want—this step in your real code, unless you need to add it in for some quick temporary debugging.)

```
>>> groups = [(name, list(group)) for name, group in groups]
>>> groups
[('Jim',
  [{'sesion_id': '86487asr341542343dlrasd4',
    'customer id': 'Jim',
    'time': '2014-07-29 12:15:48.113',
    'activity': 'view cart'}]),
 ('Tom',
  [{'sesion_id': '86487asr341542343dwrasd4',
    'customer id': 'Tom',
    'time': '2014-07-29 12:15:45.113',
    'activity': 'view cart'},
   {'sesion_id': '86487asr341542343dwrasd4',
    'customer id': 'Tom',
    'time': '2014-07-29 12:17:48.113',
    'activity': 'checkout'}])]
```

Now you've got something that's a lot easier to transform into whatever form you wanted:

```
>>> user_activity = [
    {'customer': name,
     'activities': [
         {k: v for k, v in activity.items() if k in ('time', 'activity')}
         for activity in group]
    } for name, group in groups]
```

So, putting it all together into one giant (non-mutating, declarative) expression:

```
>>> user_activity = [
    {'customer': name,
     'activities': [
         {k: v for k, v in activity.items() if k in ('time', 'activity')}
         for activity in group]
    } for name, group in igroupby(
        sorted(log, key=itemgetter('customer id')),
        key=itemgetter('customer id'))]
```

But putting it all together is going exactly the wrong direction. Instead, you should be looking for complex pieces you can refactor out into out-of-line functions or separate transformations. It's still declarative that way, but it's also readable. If you used this as-is in real-life code, anyone who has to work on or otherwise read that code would be within their rights to shoot you. :)

This, on the other hand, might be readable and maintainable:

```
def dictfilter(d, keys):
    return {k: v for k, v in d.items() if k in keys}

def transform_log(log):
    filt = functools.partial(dictfilter, keys=('time', 'activity'))
    keyfunc = operator.itemgetter('customer id')
    sortedlog = sorted(log, key=keyfunc)
    groups = itertools.groupby(sortedlog, key=keyfunc)
    def transform(name, group):
        return {'customer': name, 'activities': list(map(filt, activity))}
    return [transform(name, group) for name, group in groups]
```

Comment: This is an awesome explanation that does exactly what I explained, although it ended up not being exactly what I needed. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a `defaultdict` for this.  Constructors for `defaultdict`s are passed a function that is called any time a key that does not exist is tried.  A `defaultdict(list)` would create an empty list any time a new key was used.

```
from collections import defaultdict
user_activity = defaultdict(list)
for d in log:
    customer_id = d['customer id']
    del d['customer id']
    user_activity[customer_id].append(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a list of dictionaries, it would be better to have a dict with customer id as keys and list of activities as value. Easier to fetch.

```
from collections import defaultdict

user_activity = defaultdict(list)

for item in log:
    customer = item['customer id']
    item.pop('customer id')
    user_activity[customer].append(item)
```

Comment: Use `setdefault` or a `defaultdict` and this would be better.

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the work. Explanations are in comments.

```
from itertools import groupby

# your data
log = [
    {'customer id': 'Tom',
    'activity': 'view cart',
    'time': '2014-07-29 12:15:45.113',
    'sesion_id': '86487asr341542343dwrasd4'},
    {'customer id': 'Jim',
    'activity': 'view cart',
    'time': '2014-07-29 12:15:48.113',
    'sesion_id': '86487asr341542343dlrasd4'},
    {'customer id': 'Tom',
    'activity': 'checkout',
    'time': '2014-07-29 12:17:48.113',
    'sesion_id': '86487asr341542343dwrasd4'}
]


keyfunc = lambda x: x['customer id'] 
groups = []
uniquekeys = []
log = sorted(log, key=keyfunc)
ignore_fields = ["customer id", "sesion_id"] # fields that you don't want to put in "activities" in user_activity
# group log by "customer id", and construct user_activity list iterating over the groups
# the value of "activities" is a list of dict, and the dict only includes value with keys that are not in ignore_fields
user_activity = [
                    {
                        "customer": key, 
                        "activities": 
                            [
                                {k:v for k, v in d.iteritems() if k not in ignore_fields}
                                for d in group
                            ]
                    } 
                    for key, group in groupby(log, keyfunc)
                ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's convenient to use **pandas** library for these kind of things:

1) create a dataframe from your log object;

2) group by customer;

3) for each group create a dictionary, and combine all dictionaries using list comprehension. To unpack each group's dataframe into a list, use to_dict() method.

The below code is self-explanatory:

```
import pandas as pd
groups = pd.DataFrame(log).groupby('customer id')
user_activity = [ { 'customer' : key, 
                'activities' : value[['activity','time']].T.to_dict().values() } 
                for key, value in groups ]
```